# Notation random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

I sometimes read the notation $$P[X \in d\omega].$$ I don't know what it means, how to pick the elements, the random variable is mapped to, to a "set" (which is none), or more precisely a variable with respect to we are integrating.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 4):

It's a notation for the [pushforward measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) of $X$:

$$\mu(B) := \mathbb{P}[X \in B] = \mathbb{P} (\{w \in \Omega; X(w)\in B\})$$

then

$$\int f(X) \, \mathbb{P}(dw)=\int f \, \mathbb{P}[X \in dw] = \int f \, \mu(dw)$$

holds.